# How can I allow a single space in a regex in Dart but allow other characters to be 1 or more?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, regular-language

I've looked through tons of stuff and all point to just add a space in the regex but it doesn't work for me, can you explain why and how can I make it work?

Right now the expression I am using is this and its written in javascript which means it allows the user to use \s for space but in dart its just a single space " ".

```
RegExp(r'''^[\w\'\’\"_,.()&!*|:/\\–%-]+(?:\s[\w\'\’\"_,.()&!*|:/\\–%-]+)*?\s?$''');
```

I am trying to accept only alpha-numeric characters at start of the string and then after a character or word it should only allow a single space but other characters can be more than that.

This is how I am using it in my code.

```
inputFormatters: [
                        RegexInputFormatter(featureRegex),
                 ],
```

```
class RegexInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  final RegExp regex;

  RegexInputFormatter(this.regex);

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final String newText = newValue.text;
    final String filteredText = _getFilteredText(newText);
    if (newText != filteredText) {
      final int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end - (newText.length - filteredText.length);
      return TextEditingValue(
        text: filteredText,
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
      );
    }
    return newValue;
  }
```

For example,

Accepted strings:

- abfed124
- sfaasf(space)1221
- afasf(space).124,(space)aaf
- 1242dsdd(space)sddl,.!
- 1242dsdd(space)sddl,,...!!!!

Non-Acceptable strings:

- (space)(space)asfa
- (space)asf112
- @ajsfas
- aas(space)(space)(space),asa(space)(space)(space)as

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this regex

```
RegExp regex = RegExp(r'^(?!.*\s\s)[\w,.! ]+$');
```

Comment: Thanks and it works fine on paper but still not working in dart. Maybe I need to adjust the code somehow.

Comment: Okay I figured it out, Thanks alot

Comment: class CustomInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {

    if(newValue.text.length < oldValue.text.length) {
      return newValue;
    }
    if (!regex.hasMatch(newValue.text)) {
      return oldValue;
    }
    return newValue;
  }
}


This works !!

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
void main() {
  RegExp r = RegExp(r'^[^\s]*(?:\s[^\s]*)?$');

  String input1 = "HelloWorld";      // Valid
  String input2 = "Hello World";     // Valid
  String input3 = "Hello!123";       // Valid
  String input4 = "SpecialChars@#";  // Valid
  String input5 = "Too  Many Spaces"; // Invalid due to two spaces

  print(r.hasMatch(input1)); // true
  print(r.hasMatch(input2)); // true
  print(r.hasMatch(input3)); // true
  print(r.hasMatch(input4)); // true
  print(r.hasMatch(input5)); // false
}
```